# How to shorten this code for making a grayscale picture?

Tags: image, numpy, python-3.7, rgb

I have written a code to change my imported image into a grayscale image. 
I was not allowed to use ready-made functions. 
The shape should be (Y, X, 3) and the dtype of the numpy array is ’uint8’.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def turn_image_to_grey(image):
# 
    R = np.array(img[:, :, 0])
    G = np.array(img[:, :, 1])
    B = np.array(img[:, :, 2])

    R = R / 3             
    G = G / 3
    B = B / 3

    new_value = (R + G + B) 
# 
    grey = image.copy()   
    for value in range(3):
        grey[:,:,value] = new_value

    return plt.imshow(grey)

turn_image_to_grey(img)
```

Here, img is an image I have already imported.
I should be able to write the part making the new_value shorter (the part between the hashtags), right? By using *np.average*. 
But how can I do this?

Comment: The link above should help. One thing that's notable is that the accepted answer weights the color channels appropriately to map well to greyscale given the cones in typical human eye.

Comment: Did you try using `np.average` at all?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sure, did not work ;(. But I'm learning python, everything is new to me, so that's why.

Comment: It should be as simple as `np.average(img, axis=2)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, works, thank you! Now the whole code part between the hashtags above is  unnecessary, isn't it? :)